# How to set parameter for onClick event

Tags: reactjs

I am building a page selector for search results. I am using the following code to build the elements:

```
numbers.map(item=>{
                    counter ++
                    return(
                        <div className={'number-holder'} key={counter} onClick={() => changePage({counter})}>{counter}</div>
                    )
                })
```

The issue is this part:

```
changePage({counter})
```

It always returns the last value of the COUNTER variable, no matter which item it is. So, if there are 10 pages, and I click '5', it still returns '10'.

The use of COUNTER for the key and text between the DIV works, but for the function, it only returns the last value of COUNTER.

How an I change this so the changePage() function returns the correct number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index of the map method can be used to get the correct offset:

```
numbers.map((item, index) => {
    return (
        <div className={'number-holder'} key={index} onClick={() => changePage({counter: index})}>{index}</div>
    )
})
```

You could also add `+1` to show it as normal numbers:

```
numbers.map((item, index) => {
    return (
        <div className={'number-holder'} key={index} onClick={() => changePage({counter: index + 1})}>{index + 1}</div>
    )
})
```

Please note that using the index as key is not recommended, is it preferred to use an id of the object such as `item.id`. Read more about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: I guess the error was caused the `changePage` method expecting the `counter` field. I updated the example to show how this can be accomplished. You should be able to accept the answer. @LeeLoftiss

Comment: YOur last little bit there about using the index for the key. Makes sense. Since I am just using numbers, prefixing the number with a DOMAIN text should work, right? ex: 'page_picker_{index}'

Comment: No the problem with using indexes is that they change if the order of the `numbers` array changes. This means the element with the previous key=1 could be a totally different element when changing the order of the elements. Because if this React isn't able to cache the element. This won't cause bugs but it can cause some overhead. Adding a namespace wouldn't fix the problem because the indexes could end up pointing to a different time because using `index`. Using `id` is recommended because they stay unique to the element.

Comment: Thanks. So perhaps I should create a array of numbers that represent the pages then iterate through those to create the elements. Does that sound better?

Comment: That wouldn't solve the problem, a possible solution is to create an array with the page objects. Each page object could contain a `name` and `id`, this array can then be used with `.map`. The div in the `return` section could then use the unique `id` from the page object as unique key.

Comment: I see I was not clear about what I was working on. This is for selecting pages of search results. So the pages don't actually exist. Thanks for all your help. I will keep your feedback in mind when I do this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a property in the item from index  look

```
numbers.map(item => {
    return (
        <div className={'number-holder'} key={item.id} onClick={() => changePage({counter: item.id+ 1})}>{index + 1}</div>
    )
})
```

or can ued the secand parameter in map for index element

```
numbers.map((item,index) => {
        return (
            <div className={'number-holder'} key={index} onClick={() => changePage({counter: item.id+ 1})}>{index + 1}</div>
        )
    })
```

i perfare to used the the first option tell me in commit if it work or not

Comment: Thanks Mohammed. But someone already gave the same answer. It does work.